# Why can't /usr/bin/cd go to $OLDPWD

Tags: bash

Ran into something interesting that I can't quite figure out the reason for. Whenever I use bash's builtin cd, I can use `cd -`, but when I use the cd executable it errors out with an error saying: `/usr/bin/cd: line 2: cd: OLDPWD not set`

Here's a transcript:

```
$ cd /tmp
$ cd $HOME
$ echo $OLDPWD 
/tmp 
$ /usr/bin/cd - 
/usr/bin/cd: line 2: cd: OLDPWD not set 
$ declare -xp OLDPWD 
declare -x OLDPWD="/tmp"
```

Comment: What do you mean with `/usr/bin/cd` ?

Comment: @hek2mgl I have a binary at the location /usr/bin/cd

Comment: cd is not a binary in that folder.

Comment: Such a binary is pointless. Check @glglgl's answer

Comment: @hek2mgl I did, makes sense.

Comment: The answer is here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50058/what-is-the-point-of-the-cd-external-command (Thanks to a co-worker who found that! :) .. Good question!

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure where this `cd` executable comes from, but it is pointless: All it can do is change its own wd, but not the caller's (i. e. the shell's). So `cd` is necessarily a builtin and can only work as such.

Comment: I'm on a fedora 22 machine and it seems to have one, you're right about it being pointless, I didn't think of that.

Comment: I can confirm that Fedora ships that script. `yum whatprovides /usr/bin/cd` revealed that it is part of the `bash` package. I'm investigating what maintainers had in mind..

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer in `#bash` on irc.freenode.net

Looks like the `/usr/bin/cd` executable is not a real binary:

```
$ cat /usr/bin/cd
#!/bin/sh
builtin cd "$@"
```

Which means /usr/bin/cd is run in a subshell running `sh`, whenever `sh` is started, it ignores/unsets `PWD` and `OLDPWD` defined by the parent shell, therefore it seems it can't find `$OLDPWD`

Comment: That's not the point: many files in `/usr/bin` aren't binaries. And `$OLDPWD` is evaluated by the calling shell, so no need for the child process to have access to this.

Comment: Why wouldn't it make sense for a child process to have access to OLDPWD? It could still use it for something else? If it really isn't needed, then why does bash export it by default?

Comment: I don't know that, but it is just not relevant here: if you call `/usr/bin/cd "$OLDPWD"`, the `"$OLDPWD"` is evaluated by the caller and the `cd` script only sees its content.